# Conditional assignment syntax error in python 2.7.1 (but not in 2.7.3 ?) only occurs running from bash

Tags: python

The following code is fine on 2.7.3, but is giving syntax error on 2.7.1.  Am I compelled to rewrite this as a four line if <>:  else:   construct in 2.7.1? Or is there something else going on?

Error in 2.7.1 (works in 2.7.3):

```
    stub=(sys.argv[ix].lower()=='true' if len(sys.argv)>ix else False)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was surprised because had thought that the minor version number diff 2.7.3 vs 2.7.1 only were bug fixes, not functionality.

**Update**: this problem only occurs when the script is run as bash directly. i.e. "./test.py" as opposed to "python test.py".  And also the error does only happen in 2.7.1 (2.7.3 is happy either way)

I have created full mini program that passes in python test.py in either 2.7.3 or  2.7.1 and passes as ./test.py in 2.7.3  but **fails in ./test.py running under 2.7.1**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

ix=1
stub=sys.argv[ix].lower()=='true' if len(sys.argv)>ix else False
print stub
```

Running under 2.7.1:

```
$ ./test.py
  File "./test.py", line 5
    stub=sys.argv[ix].lower()=='true' if len(sys.argv)>ix else False
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Running under 2.7.3:

```
$ ./test.py
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rearranging your expression

```
stub = sys.argv[ix].lower() == 'true' if len(sys.argv) > ix else False
```

or if it is more to your eyes

```
stub = (sys.argv[ix].lower() == 'true') if len(sys.argv) > ix else False
```

Comment: thx apparently 2.7.1 does not like the whole expression in parentheses. Any idea why?

Comment: Well... as you've said minor versions fix bugs. Guess one was in lexical analyser;)

Comment: stub = (len(sys.argv) > ix and sys.argv[ix].lower() == 'true')

Answer (score 1):

According to [the 2.5 release notes](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308) conditional expressions were installed then, and I can confirm they work in 2.7.2 edit: and 2.7.1. I would guess the problem is on the previous line of code.

Comment: turns out the problem is 2.7.1 can not handle the entire statement within parentheses.  I don't claim to understand (a) why that's a problem and (b) why the behavior would have changed in minor point release 2.7.1 to 2.7.3 (i had developed/tested in 2.7.3 where the syntax is fine)

Comment: That's strange, as when I tested a statement of the form
`a = (b if c else d)` worked on 2.7.1 for me...

Comment: See my updated post. Has to do with running as bash script. And only under 2.7.1.